# Is there a package with standard theorem environments and math functions

Tags: packages, environments

I would like a package that defines nice things by default like:

1. Theorem environments like definition, property, example etc.
2. Standard includes like subfloats, the amsmath family
3. Reference functions like `\sectionref`, `\algorithmref` etc.
4. Math functions like `\argmin`, `\trace`, etc.

Essentially, I would like all the settings of the JMLR class, but be able to use it in a separate class (something for a thesis). I have tried modifying the secondary class (`thesis.cls`) to use JMLR as the base (`\LoadClassWithOptions`), however it complains because I need to use chapters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

environment names used for theorem-class objects are usually very subjective, which is one reason they aren't usually predefined.

if you like the ones in the jmlr class, you can just create your own package by copying into it the `\theoremstyle` and `\newtheorem` definitions from jmlr, call the package `mydefs.sty`, and then `\usepackage{mydefs}`.

be prepared, however, to be requested to incorporate the actual definitions in your source file if you submit an article for publication.  publishers don't like to mess with home-grown packages, for very good reasons.

Comment: Alright. I usually save all these commands into a single file and include them using \input. Is there any reason to prefer a pacakge to this approach?

Comment: @arunchaganty -- if you have any need to define commands that involve `@` signs, the mechanism for `\usepackage` invokes `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` automatically.  of course, if you then have to incorporate your definitions into your source file, you'd have to include those commands explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, I would like all the settings of the JMLR class, but be
>   able to use it in a separate class (something for a thesis).

As from version 1.24, the [`jmlr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/jmlr) class now has the class-independent code in a separate package `jdrutils`. This is automatically loaded by the `jmlr` class, but may be used with other classes. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{jmlrutils}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Sample Section}
\label{sec:sample}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2\label{eq:E}
\end{equation}

\section{Another Sample Section}
\label{sec:anothersample}

Linear equation:
\begin{equation}
y = mx + c\label{eq:linear}
\end{equation}

Quadratic equation:
\begin{equation}
y = ax^2 + bx + c\label{eq:quad}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Another}

Reference \sectionref{sec:sample,sec:anothersample}
and \equationref{eq:E,eq:linear,eq:quad}.

\end{document}
```

The second page:

[image: Chapter 2 Another Reference Sections 1.1 and 1.2 and Equations (1.1), (1.2) and (1.3).]

There's no `\chapterref`, but one can be defined in a similar way to `\sectionref`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{jmlrutils}

\newcommand*{\chapterrefname}{Chapter}
\newcommand*{\chaptersrefname}{Chapters}

\newcommand*{\chapterref}[1]{%
  \objectref{#1}{\chapterrefname}{\chaptersrefname}{}{}}    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\label{ch:sample}

\section{Sample Section}
\label{sec:sample}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2\label{eq:E}
\end{equation}

\section{Another Sample Section}
\label{sec:anothersample}

Linear equation:
\begin{equation}
y = mx + c\label{eq:linear}
\end{equation}

Quadratic equation:
\begin{equation}
y = ax^2 + bx + c\label{eq:quad}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Another}

Reference \chapterref{ch:sample}, \sectionref{sec:sample,sec:anothersample}
and \equationref{eq:E,eq:linear,eq:quad}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Chapter 2 Another Reference Chapter 1, Sections 1.1 and 1.2 and Equations (1.1), (1.2) and (1.3).]